# MongoDB Schema design Student Exams

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am trying to learn **MongoDB with Nodejs** and using **mongoose**, and know basic stuff, (I am from a SQL Background). I am trying to make a student exam Database.

There are multiple exams, each exam has some students, that are going to take some MCQ questions and answer the questions which I need to save.

As I am new to NoSQL, so I am looking for models for these requirements. (personal learning project)

Here are my example objects, which I need to model

```
// Exam Object
{
    "ExamID":  "1",
    "ExamDate": "2021-01-01 09:00:00",
    "ExamName": "Midterm Exam"
}

// student Object
{
    "StudentID":  "1",
    "StudentName": "SOME FULL NAME"
}

// Question Object
{
    "ExamQuestions":[
        {
            "QuestionID":  "1",
            "QuestionText": "SOME Long QUestion Text",
            "Correct": "A",
            "QuestionOptions":[
                {
                    "Option_Title": "A",
                    "Option_Value": "This is Option A"
                },
                {
                    "Option_Title": "B",
                    "Option_Value": "This is Option B"
                },
                {
                    "Option_Title": "C",
                    "Option_Value": "This is Option C"
                },
                {
                    "Option_Title": "D",
                    "Option_Value": "This is Option D"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
    
}

// students answer to questions Object

{
    "Students":[
        {
            "StudentID":"1",
            "Answers":[
                {
                    "QuestionID": "1",
                    "ANSWER": "A"   
                },
                {
                    "QuestionID": "2",
                    "ANSWER": "B"   
                },
                {
                    "QuestionID": "3",
                    "ANSWER": "D"   
                }
                
            ]
        },
        {
            "StudentID":"2",
            "Answers":[
                {
                    "QuestionID": "1",
                    "ANSWER": "B"   
                },
                {
                    "QuestionID": "2",
                    "ANSWER": "C"   
                },
                {
                    "QuestionID": "3",
                    "ANSWER": "A"   
                }
                
            ]
        }
    ]

}
```

Answer (score 1):

So with mongoDB there are two ways that I know in where you can deal with one-to-many, you have the embedded approach and referencing approach.

**Embedded approach what is that?**

(So I will step back a bit from your **exam** example cause I do not know how I can explain with that but I will try my best to break down relationships in mongo)

- So with embedded lets say we have model for user post(Like in a social media app) so a post has comments right and **one post** can have **many comments**

**So we can have a document like this**

```
{

    _id:54844838asd3843aereaf,
    user:John Doe,
    comments:[

        {
           usercomment:"random text",
        }

    ]
}
```

- So lets say that now another user were to comment then when using the embedded approach you basically pushing new comments in that array and then update that document so to have those new comments while maintaining the old ones

**Second approach: Referencing**

- So here what happens is, if we do take that example from above about user post and comment
- So what you want to do is to have two models **user post model** and **comments model** but then your user post model must make reference to the comments model what do I mean by this

**So below we make a comments model**

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const commentsModel = mongoose.model(

    "commentsModel",

    new mongoose.Schema({

        commentedUser:{type:String, required:true},
        commment:{type:String, required:true} 

    })

)
```

**Now we need to have a post model then have each post ref comments model**

```
const postModel = mongoose.model(

    "userPost",

    new mongoose.Schema({

        user:{type:String, required:true},
        post:{type:String, required:true},

        comments:[

          {
       
            type:mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId
            ref:"commentsModel"
            //So here I reference the commentsModel and on each entry 
            //I insert only the id of that comment

          }

       ]

    })

)
```

- So now how the procedure would work is lets say you receive a comment from user you take that comment save in commentModel
- Finally take that **_id** given back by mongoose and **push** to your array of comments (So key is to store that comment id in your comments array )

**If my explanation did not fully make sense to you, you can refer to docs they clear**

https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/model-referenced-one-to-many-relationships-between-documents/

**You can also check this blog out with regards to that for more clarity if docs don't make sense**

https://medium.com/@brandon.lau86/one-to-many-relationships-with-mongodb-and-mongoose-in-node-express-d5c9d23d93c2

**Final last resort is YouTube what best than to hear someone explain**

https://youtu.be/t_9fgpsO_vM

Comment: as I said, I have basic information about mongoose and nodejs. I need the detailed schemas of the above objects , so that i can understand how the relational data is stored in MongoDB

Comment: So do you want me to give full detailed information on everything explaining how you'd go about making operations?

Comment: not at all, I know how to write the operations and logic. what I am lacking is the models' relations. I have models of individual objects, but how to link models that exam 1 has 50 students and these 50 students have X answers. once again, i know the oprtations, and login, just could not get the linking of models.

Comment: Basically what you want to achieve in this case is like a one-to-many relation within your collections?

Comment: yes, exactly, I am new to NOSQL, so need to figureout how relations work in it

Comment: OKay I guess let me edit my answer to answer you fully